# emacs erc notification don't work

Tags: emacs, elisp

I want to be notified when someone addresses me on irc. But some reason I can't achieve that.

I tried to set the list `erc-modules` to include `notifications` like so:

```
(require 'erc)
(add-to-list 'erc-modules 'notifications)
(erc-update-modules)
```

It was giving me:

```
Symbol's value as variable is void: notifications
```

So then I simply did

```
M-x customize option
erc-modules
```

There I clicked the "notifications" options. And the following was saved to my .emacs file:

```
(custom-set-variables
 ...
'(erc-modules (quote (autojoin button completion fill irccontrols list log match menu move-to-prompt netsplit networks noncommands notifications readonly ring stamp track)))
 ...
 )
```

But I still have no notifications. By the way, I left the first code block, from above, in .emacs file. Its still at the very bottom of the .emacs file, after everything else.

So my question is how do I set erc to notify me when someone is addressing a message at me?

Thanks in advance for your kind help and time.

Jenia.

Comment: hehe. the (add-to-list ...) code works after I do (custom-set-varibles...). I tried to do what you said. The first and the second suggestion. It didnt work. Also I did (setq erc-modules..). With the tick it gives me: Wrong type argument: symbolp, (quote erc-modules). Maybe there's something else I can try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the manual ( https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/erc/Modules.html ), one method would be to:  (1) set erc-modules manually; and, (2) then call `erc-update-modules`.

My interpretation of that is as follows:

```lisp
(require 'erc)

(setq erc-modules '(
  autojoin
  button
  completion
  fill
  irccontrols
  list
  log
  match
  menu
  move-to-prompt
  netsplit
  networks
  noncommands
  notifications
  readonly
  ring
  stamp
  track))

(erc-update-modules)
```

---

Your other `erc` settings should be removed.

Comment: okay. i see it works. thanks a lot. Do you know how to change the color of the notification?

Comment: Place your cursor on the notification color that you want to change and type:  `C-u C-x =`  That will tell you what font face is being used, and you can then change the font face to your liking -- e.g., `M-x customize-face`

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar error: `‘notifications’ is not a known ERC module`.
Lawlist's solution doesn't work for me.

Adding `(require 'erc-desktop-notifications)` solved my problem.

inspiration: [Yez Ezey - How to get notifications from Erc in macOS?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/51233/11777)